# php function to split a description into lines 68 chars long

Tags: php, pdf

Im just wondering if anyone can help me out. Iv been trying to figure this out all day.
I have these variables

```
$booking['occasion']
$booking['date']
$booking['venue']
```

and I want to make a description out of them like this.

$description = "Deposit for supplying a DJ for an $occasion on the 
$date in  the $venue";

I want to display the description over 3 or 4 lines in a pdf file like this

```
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(139, 5, '20', '125', $line1, '', 1, 1, true, 'L', true);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(139, 5, '25', '125', $line2, '', 1, 1, true, 'L', true);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(139, 5, '30', '125', $line3, '', 1, 1, true, 'L', true);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(139, 5, '35', '125', $line4, '', 1, 1, true, 'L', true);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(139, 5, '40', '125', $line5, '', 1, 1, true, 'L', true);
```

I want to wrap the description to a next line after every 68 characters but only want to wrap after completed words

Can anyone help me create a function to split the desicprtion into 3 or 4 lines so far I have this code which I know is along the lines that I want.

```
$description = "Deposit for suppling a DJ and Equipment for a $occasion on the 
$date in $venue";
$decriptionLength = strlen($description);
if($decriptionLength <= 68){
  $line1 = $description;    
}
elseif($decriptionLength > 68)
{
  $line1 = substr($description, 0, 68);
  $line2 = substr($description, 68, 136);
}
```

This code will wrap the text even in the middle of a word so I don’t want this.
I know this might be a lot to ask but if anyone can come up with some code I would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [`wordwrap()`](http://www.php.net/wordwrap)?

Answer (score 0):

The `wordwrap()` function may help.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

```
$wordwrapped = wordwrap($description, 139, "\n");

$lines = explode("\n", $wordwrapped);

$line1 = $lines[0];
$line2 = $lines[1];

if (count($lines) > 3) {

    $third_line = "";

    for ($idx = 1; $idx < count($lines); $idx++) {
        $third_line .= $lines[$idx] . " ";
    }

    $line3 = $third_line;

}

else {

    $line3 = $lines[2];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. i am getting an error at the 2nd line " Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed" any ideas?